# Is it to be expected that the client will discover each node twice for the Hazelcast sidecar caching pattern?

Tags: spring-boot, caching, hazelcast, sidecar

I'm pretty new to using Hazelcast for its interesting feature of auto-sync with other cache instances. My queries are bottom of the description.

**Here was my initial goal:**

1. Design an environment following **Hazelcast sidecar caching** pattern.
2. There will be no cache on the application container side. Basically, I don't want to use "near-cache" just to avoid my JVM being heavy and reduce GC time.
3. **Application Container** in each **Node** will communicate with its own sidecar cache container via localhost IP.
4. **Hazelcast management center** will be a separate node that communicates with all the nodes containing **Hazelcast sidecar cache** container.

**Here is the target design:**
[image]

I prepared Hazelcast configuration [hazelcast.yaml] for Hazelcast container,

```yaml
    hazelcast:
    cluster-name: dev
    network:
    port:
      auto-increment: false
      port-count: 3
      port: 5701
```

I also prepared another hazelcast.yaml for my application container,

```yaml
    hazelcast:
      map:
        default:
          backup-count: 0
          async-backup-count: 1
          read-backup-data: true
      network:
        reuse-address: true
        port:
          auto-increment: true
          port: 5701
        join:
          multicast:
            enabled: true
          kubernetes:
            enabled: false
          tcp-ip:
            enabled: false
            interaface: 127.0.0.1
            member-list:
              - 127.0.0.1:5701
```

Here is the client part, I used SpringBoot for it.

```java
    @Component
    public class CacheClient {
        
        private static final String ITEMS = "items";
        
        private HazelcastInstance client;

        CacheClient() throws IOException {
            ClientConfig config = new YamlClientConfigBuilder("hazelcast.yaml").build();
            config.setInstanceName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            client = HazelcastClient.getOrCreateHazelcastClient(config);
        }
    
        public Item put(String number, Item item){
            IMap<String, Item> map = client.getMap(ITEMS);
            return map.putIfAbsent(number, item);
        }
    
        public Item get(String key){
            IMap<String, Item> map = client.getMap(ITEMS);
            return map.get(key);
        }
    }
```

Here is the dockerfile, I used to build my application container image,

```sh
    FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.5_10-alpine-slim
    # Expose port 8081 to Docker host
    EXPOSE 8081
    WORKDIR /opt
    COPY /build/libs/hazelcast-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/app.jar
    COPY /src/main/resources/hazelcast.yaml /opt/hazelcast.yaml
    COPY /src/main/resources/application.properties /opt/application.properties
    ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dhazelcast.socket.server.bind.any=false","-Dhazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size=1","-Dhazelcast.socket.bind.any=false","-Dhazelcast.socket.server.bind.any=false","-Dhazelcast.socket.client.bind=false","-Dhazelcast.socket.client.bind.any=false","-Dhazelcast.logging.type=slf4j","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Here is the deployment script I used,

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1 # Kubernetes API version
    kind: Service # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
    metadata: # Metadata of the resource kind we are creating
      name: spring-hazelcast-service
    spec:
      selector:
        app: spring-hazelcast-app
      ports:
        - protocol: "TCP"
          name: http-app
          port: 8081 # The port that the service is running on in the cluster
          targetPort: 8081 # The port exposed by the service
      type: LoadBalancer # type of the service. LoadBalancer indicates that our service will be external.
    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
    metadata:
      name: spring-hazelcast-app
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: spring-hazelcast-app
      replicas: 1 # Number of replicas that will be created for this deployment
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: spring-hazelcast-app
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: hazelcast
              image: hazelcast/hazelcast:4.0.2
              workingDir: /opt
              ports:
                - name: hazelcast
                  containerPort: 5701
              env:
                - name: HZ_CLUSTERNAME
                  value: dev
                - name: JAVA_OPTS
                  value: -Dhazelcast.config=/opt/config/hazelcast.yml
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: "/opt/config/"
                  name: allconf
            - name: spring-hazelcast-app
              image: spring-hazelcast:1.0.3
              imagePullPolicy: Never #IfNotPresent
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8081 # The port that the container is running on in the cluster
          volumes:
            - name: allconf
              hostPath:
                path: /opt/config/   # directory location on host
                type: Directory # this field is optional
    ---
    apiVersion: v1 # Kubernetes API version
    kind: Service # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
    metadata: # Metadata of the resource kind we are creating
      name: hazelcast-mc-service
    spec:
      selector:
        app: hazelcast-mc
      ports:
        - protocol: "TCP"
          name: mc-app
          port: 8080 # The port that the service is running on in the cluster
          targetPort: 8080 # The port exposed by the service
      type: LoadBalancer # type of the
      loadBalancerIP: "127.0.0.1"
    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment # Kubernetes resource kind we are creating
    metadata:
      name: hazelcast-mc
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: hazelcast-mc
      replicas: 1 # Number of replicas that will be created for this deployment
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: hazelcast-mc
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: hazelcast-mc
              image: hazelcast/management-center
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8080 # The port that the container is running on in the cluster
```

Here is my application logs,

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.4)
    
    2021-09-27 06:42:51.274  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.caching.Application                  : Starting Application using Java 11.0.5 on spring-hazelcast-app-7bdc8b7f7-bqdlt with PID 1 (/opt/app.jar started by root in /opt)
    2021-09-27 06:42:51.278  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.caching.Application                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2021-09-27 06:42:55.986  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.c.impl.spi.ClientInvocationService   : b1bdd9bb-2879-4161-95fd-2b6e321ad30a [dev] [4.0.2] Running with 2 response threads, dynamic=true
    2021-09-27 06:42:56.199  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : b1bdd9bb-2879-4161-95fd-2b6e321ad30a [dev] [4.0.2] HazelcastClient 4.0.2 (20200702 - 2de3027) is STARTING
    2021-09-27 06:42:56.202  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : b1bdd9bb-2879-4161-95fd-2b6e321ad30a [dev] [4.0.2] HazelcastClient 4.0.2 (20200702 - 2de3027) is STARTED
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.SelectorOptimizer (jar:file:/opt/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/hazelcast-all-4.0.2.jar!/) to field sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.SelectorOptimizer
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    2021-09-27 06:42:56.277  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.c.i.c.ClientConnectionManager        : b1bdd9bb-2879-4161-95fd-2b6e321ad30a [dev] [4.0.2] Trying to connect to cluster: dev
    2021-09-27 06:42:56.302  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.c.i.c.ClientConnectionManager        : b1bdd9bb-2879-4161-95fd-2b6e321ad30a [dev] [4.0.2] Trying to connect to [127.0.0.1]:5701
    2021-09-27 06:42:56.429  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : b1bdd9bb-2879-4161-95fd-2b6e321ad30a [dev] [4.0.2] HazelcastClient 4.0.2 (20200702 - 2de3027) is CLIENT_CONNECTED
    2021-09-27 06:42:56.429  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.c.i.c.ClientConnectionManager        : b1bdd9bb-2879-4161-95fd-2b6e321ad30a [dev] [4.0.2] Authenticated with server [172.17.0.3]:5701:c967f642-a7aa-4deb-a530-b56fb8f68c78, server version: 4.0.2, local address: /127.0.0.1:54373
    2021-09-27 06:42:56.436  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics     : b1bdd9bb-2879-4161-95fd-2b6e321ad30a [dev] [4.0.2] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
    2021-09-27 06:42:56.461  INFO 1 --- [21ad30a.event-4] c.h.c.impl.spi.ClientClusterService      : b1bdd9bb-2879-4161-95fd-2b6e321ad30a [dev] [4.0.2] 
    
    Members [1] {
            Member [172.17.0.3]:5701 - c967f642-a7aa-4deb-a530-b56fb8f68c78
    }
    
    2021-09-27 06:42:56.803  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.c.i.s.ClientStatisticsService        : Client statistics is enabled with period 5 seconds.
    2021-09-27 06:42:57.878  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.i.config.AbstractConfigLocator       : Loading 'hazelcast.yaml' from the working directory.
    2021-09-27 06:42:57.934  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.h.i.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory      : Hazelcast is starting in a Java modular environment (Java 9 and newer) but without proper access to required Java packages. Use additional Java arguments to provide Hazelcast access to Java internal API. The internal API access is used to get the best performance results. Arguments to be used:
     --add-modules java.se --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
    2021-09-27 06:42:57.976  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.2] Prefer IPv4 stack is true, prefer IPv6 addresses is false
    2021-09-27 06:42:57.987  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [dev] [4.0.2] Picked [172.17.0.3]:5702, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/172.17.0.3,localport=5702], bind any local is false
    2021-09-27 06:42:58.004  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] Hazelcast 4.0.2 (20200702 - 2de3027) starting at [172.17.0.3]:5702
    2021-09-27 06:42:58.005  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] Copyright (c) 2008-2020, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    2021-09-27 06:42:58.047  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.BackpressureRegulator     : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] Backpressure is disabled
    2021-09-27 06:42:58.373  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node         : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] Creating MulticastJoiner
    2021-09-27 06:42:58.380  WARN 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.cp.CPSubsystem             : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] CP Subsystem is not enabled. CP data structures will operate in UNSAFE mode! Please note that UNSAFE mode will not provide strong consistency guarantees.
    2021-09-27 06:42:58.676  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] Starting 2 partition threads and 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
    2021-09-27 06:42:58.682  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics     : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
    
    
    2021-09-27 06:42:58.687  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] [172.17.0.3]:5702 is STARTING
    2021-09-27 06:42:58.923  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner       : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] Trying to join to discovered node: [172.17.0.3]:5701
    2021-09-27 06:42:58.932  INFO 1 --- [cached.thread-3] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector      : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] Connecting to /172.17.0.3:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: false
    2021-09-27 06:42:58.955  INFO 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-0] c.h.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection     : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] Initialized new cluster connection between /172.17.0.3:40242 and /172.17.0.3:5701
    2021-09-27 06:43:04.948  INFO 1 --- [21ad30a.event-3] c.h.c.impl.spi.ClientClusterService      : b1bdd9bb-2879-4161-95fd-2b6e321ad30a [dev] [4.0.2] 
    
    Members [2] {
            Member [172.17.0.3]:5701 - c967f642-a7aa-4deb-a530-b56fb8f68c78
            Member [172.17.0.3]:5702 - 08dfe633-46b2-4581-94c7-81b6d0bc3ce3
    }
    
    2021-09-27 06:43:04.959  WARN 1 --- [ration.thread-0] c.h.c.i.operation.OnJoinCacheOperation   : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] This member is joining a cluster whose members support JCache, however the cache-api artifact is missing from this member's classpath. In case JCache API will be used, add cache-api artifact in this member's classpath and restart the member.
    2021-09-27 06:43:04.963  INFO 1 --- [ration.thread-0] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] 
    
    Members {size:2, ver:2} [
            Member [172.17.0.3]:5701 - c967f642-a7aa-4deb-a530-b56fb8f68c78
            Member [172.17.0.3]:5702 - 08dfe633-46b2-4581-94c7-81b6d0bc3ce3 this
    ]
    
    2021-09-27 06:43:05.466  INFO 1 --- [ration.thread-1] c.h.c.i.p.t.AuthenticationMessageTask    : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] Received auth from Connection[id=2, /172.17.0.3:5702->/172.17.0.3:40773, qualifier=null, endpoint=[172.17.0.3]:40773, alive=true, connectionType=JVM], successfully authenticated, clientUuid: 8843f057-c856-4739-80ae-4bc930559bd5, client version: 4.0.2
    2021-09-27 06:43:05.468  INFO 1 --- [d30a.internal-3] c.h.c.i.c.ClientConnectionManager        : b1bdd9bb-2879-4161-95fd-2b6e321ad30a [dev] [4.0.2] Authenticated with server [172.17.0.3]:5702:08dfe633-46b2-4581-94c7-81b6d0bc3ce3, server version: 4.0.2, local address: /172.17.0.3:40773
    2021-09-27 06:43:05.968  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [172.17.0.3]:5702 [dev] [4.0.2] [172.17.0.3]:5702 is STARTED
    2021-09-27 06:43:06.237  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8081
    2021-09-27 06:43:06.251  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.caching.Application                  : Started Application in 17.32 seconds (JVM running for 21.02)
```

Here is the Hazelcast management center member list,
[image]

**Finally my question is,**

1. **Why I'm seeing 2 members, where there is only one sidecar cache container deployed?**
2. **What modification I will be required to reach my initial goal?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Spring Boot documentation for Hazelcast feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#features.hazelcast):

> If a client can’t be created, Spring Boot attempts to configure an embedded server.

Spring Boot starts an embedded server from your `hazelcast.yaml` from the application container and joins to Hazelcast container using multicast.

You should replace your `hazelcast.yaml` in the Spring Boot app container with `hazelcast-client.yaml` with the following content:

```yaml
hazelcast-client:
  cluster-name: "dev"
  network:
    cluster-members:
    - "127.0.0.1:5701"
```

After doing that Spring Boot will autoconfigure client `HazelcastInstance` bean and you will be able to change your cache client like this:

```java
@Component
public class CacheClient {
    
    private static final String ITEMS = "items";
    
    private final HazelcastInstance client;

    public CacheClient(HazelcastInstance client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Item put(String number, Item item){
        IMap<String, Item> map = client.getMap(ITEMS);
        return map.putIfAbsent(number, item);
    }

    public Item get(String key){
        IMap<String, Item> map = client.getMap(ITEMS);
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```